# What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, events, preventdefault, stoppropagation

They seem to be doing the same thing...
Is one modern and one old? Or are they supported by different browsers?

When I handle events myself (without framework) I just always check for both and execute both if present. (I also `return false`, but I have the feeling that doesn't work with events attached with `node.addEventListener`).

> So why both? Should I keep checking for both? Or is there actually a difference?

(I know, a lot of questions, but they're all sort of the same =))

Answer (score 1309, accepted):

`stopPropagation` prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

`preventDefault` prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

### Examples

**preventDefault**

```js
$("#but").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
})
$("#foo").click(function () {
  alert("parent click event fired!")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <button id="but">button</button>
</div>
```

**stopPropagation**

```js
$("#but").click(function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
})
$("#foo").click(function () {
  alert("parent click event fired!")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <button id="but">button</button>
</div>
```

With `stopPropagation`, only the **`button`'s click handler** is called while the **`div`'s click handler** never fires.

Where as if you use `preventDefault`, only the browser's default action is stopped but the div's click handler still fires.

Below are some docs on the DOM event properties and methods from MDN:

- [`event.cancelBubble`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelBubble)
- [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [`event.returnValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue)
- [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

For IE9 and FF you can just use preventDefault & stopPropagation.

To support IE8 and lower replace `stopPropagation` with `cancelBubble` and replace `preventDefault` with `returnValue`

Comment: So they're very different? Does IE have two different event methods for that too? (Might they be the same??) It's weird that frameworks do both in their `event.stop` function... Also weird I've never had trouble with that. I use bubbling a lot. Thanks for the example!

Comment: @Rudie commented on browser support.

Comment: It's worth noting (in case you don't look at the MSDN docs) that `cancelBubble` and `returnValue` are both properties (so should be set `cancelBubble = true;`), and that `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` are methods (so should be called `preventDefault();`)

Comment: Below are some docs on the DOM event objects from ```MDC``` and MSDN ```！==``` ```MDN```

Comment: stopPropagation stops the event from bubbling up or capturing (trickle down) the event chain.

Comment: @Raynos, just one note: event.stopPropagation() does not only stop the event from bubbling up the event chain, but also stop the event propagation in the capturing phase (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the default action is for a button click so I can reason about why `stopDefault()` doesn't work the same way as `stopPropagation()`. If the default action isn't calling the `onclick` method what is it?

Comment: what is the default browser behaviour for a button ?

Comment: @gaurav5430, according to the [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element), the default behaviour depends of its type and context: if it is a type submit button in a form, then the default behaviour will be to submit the form.

Answer (score 338):

## Terminology

From [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html):

> #### Event capturing
>
> When you use event capturing
>
> ```
>                | |
> ---------------| |-----------------
> | element1     | |                |
> |   -----------| |-----------     |
> |   |element2  \ /          |     |
> |   -------------------------     |
> |        Event CAPTURING          |
> -----------------------------------
> ```
>
> the event handler of element1 fires first, the event handler of element2 fires last.
>
> #### Event bubbling
>
> When you use event bubbling
>
> ```
>                / \
> ---------------| |-----------------
> | element1     | |                |
> |   -----------| |-----------     |
> |   |element2  | |          |     |
> |   -------------------------     |
> |        Event BUBBLING           |
> -----------------------------------
> ```
>
> the event handler of element2 fires first, the event handler of element1 fires last.
>
> *Any event taking place in the W3C event model is first captured until it reaches the target element and then bubbles up again*.
>
> ```
>                  | |  / \
> -----------------| |--| |-----------------
> | element1       | |  | |                |
> |   -------------| |--| |-----------     |
> |   |element2    \ /  | |          |     |
> |   --------------------------------     |
> |        W3C event model                 |
> ------------------------------------------
> ```

## Interface

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html), for *event capture*:

> If the capturing `EventListener` wishes to prevent further processing of
>   the event from occurring it may call the `stopPropagation` method of the
>   `Event` interface. This will prevent further dispatch of the event,
>   although additional `EventListeners` registered at the same hierarchy
>   level will still receive the event. Once an event's `stopPropagation`
>   method has been called, further calls to that method have no
>   additional effect. If no additional capturers exist and
>   `stopPropagation` has not been called, the event triggers the
>   appropriate `EventListeners` on the target itself.

For *event bubbling*:

> Any event handler may choose to prevent further event propagation by
>   calling the `stopPropagation` method of the `Event` interface. If any
>   `EventListener` calls this method, all additional `EventListeners` on the
>   current `EventTarget` will be triggered but bubbling will cease at that
>   level. Only one call to `stopPropagation` is required to prevent further
>   bubbling.

For *event cancelation*:

> Cancelation is accomplished by calling the `Event`'s `preventDefault`
>   method. If one or more `EventListeners` call `preventDefault` during
>   any phase of event flow the default action will be canceled.

## Examples

In the following examples, a click on the hyperlink in the web browser triggers the event's flow (the event listeners are executed) and the event target's default action (a new tab is opened).

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
  <a id="b" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>
</div>
<p id="c"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById("c");

function capturingOnClick1(ev) {
    el.innerHTML += "DIV event capture<br>";
}

function capturingOnClick2(ev) {
    el.innerHTML += "A event capture<br>";
}

function bubblingOnClick1(ev) {
    el.innerHTML += "DIV event bubbling<br>";
}

function bubblingOnClick2(ev) {
    el.innerHTML += "A event bubbling<br>";
}

// The 3rd parameter useCapture makes the event listener capturing (false by default)
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click", capturingOnClick1, true);
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", capturingOnClick2, true);
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click", bubblingOnClick1, false);
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", bubblingOnClick2, false);
```

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/wAr74/471/): it results in the output

```
DIV event capture
A event capture
A event bubbling
DIV event bubbling
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wAr74/472/): adding `stopPropagation()` to the function

```
function capturingOnClick1(ev) {
    el.innerHTML += "DIV event capture<br>";
    ev.stopPropagation();
}
```

results in the output

```
DIV event capture
```

The event listener prevented further downward and upward propagation of the event. However it did not prevent the default action (a new tab opening).

[Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/wAr74/473/): adding `stopPropagation()` to the function

```
function capturingOnClick2(ev) {
    el.innerHTML += "A event capture<br>";
    ev.stopPropagation();
}
```

or the function

```
function bubblingOnClick2(ev) {
    el.innerHTML += "A event bubbling<br>";
    ev.stopPropagation();
}
```

results in the output

```
DIV event capture
A event capture
A event bubbling
```

This is because both event listeners are registered on the same event target. The event listeners prevented further upward propagation of the event. However they did not prevent the default action (a new tab opening).

[Example 4](http://jsfiddle.net/wAr74/474/): adding `preventDefault()` to any function, for instance

```
function capturingOnClick1(ev) {
    el.innerHTML += "DIV event capture<br>";
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

prevents a new tab from opening.

Comment: Thanks for the deeper distinction between capturing and bubbling while the other answer only addresses jQuery concerns.

Answer (score 100):

**return false;**

---

`return false;` does 3 separate things when you call it:

1. `event.preventDefault()` – It stops the browsers default behaviour.
2. `event.stopPropagation()` – It prevents the event from propagating (or “bubbling up”) the DOM.
3. Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

Note that this behaviour differs from normal (non-jQuery) event handlers, in which, notably, `return false` does not stop the event from bubbling up.

**preventDefault();**

---

`preventDefault();` does one thing: It stops the browsers default behaviour.

**When to use them?**

---

We know what they do but when to use them? Simply it depends on what you want to accomplish. Use `preventDefault();` if you want to “just” prevent the default browser behaviour. Use return false; when you want to prevent the default browser behaviour and prevent the event from propagating the DOM. In most situations where you would use return false; what you really want is `preventDefault()`.

**Examples:**

---

Let’s try to understand with examples:

We will see pure JAVASCRIPT example

**Example 1:**

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='https://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    alert('Link Clicked');
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

> Run the above code you will see the hyperlink **‘Click here to visit
>   stackoverflow.com‘** now if you click on that link first you will get
>   the javascript alert **Link Clicked** Next you will get the javascript
>   alert **div Clicked** and immediately you will be redirected to
>   stackoverflow.com.

**Example 2:**

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='https://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event prevented'
    alert('Link Clicked');
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

> Run the above code you will see the hyperlink ‘Click here to visit
>   stackoverflow.com‘ now if you click on that link first you will get
>   the javascript alert **Link Clicked** Next you will get the javascript
>   alert **div Clicked** Next you will see the hyperlink ‘Click here to
>   visit stackoverflow.com‘ replaced by the text ‘Click event prevented‘
>   and you will **not** be redirected to stackoverflow.com. This is due > to event.preventDefault() method we used to prevent the default click
>   action to be triggered.

**Example 3:**

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='https://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event prevented'
    alert('Link Clicked');
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

> This time if you click on Link the function executeParent() will not
>   be called and you will not get the javascript alert **div Clicked**
>   this time. This is due to us having prevented the propagation to the
>   parent div using event.stopPropagation() method. Next you will see the
>   hyperlink ‘Click here to visit stackoverflow.com‘ replaced by the text
>   ‘Click event is going to be executed‘ and immediately you will be
>   redirected to stackoverflow.com. This is because we haven’t prevented
>   the default click action from triggering this time using
>   event.preventDefault() method.

**Example 4:**

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='https://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event prevented'
    alert('Link Clicked');
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('Div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

> If you click on the Link, the function executeParent() will not be
>   called and you will not get the javascript alert. This is due to us
>   having prevented the propagation to the parent div using
>   event.stopPropagation() method. Next you will see the hyperlink ‘Click
>   here to visit stackoverflow.com‘ replaced by the text ‘Click event
>   prevented‘ and you will not be redirected to stackoverflow.com. This
>   is because we have prevented the default click action from triggering
>   this time using event.preventDefault() method.

**Example 5:**

> **For return false I have three examples and all appear to be doing the exact same thing (just returning false), but in reality the
>   results are quite different. Here's what actually happens in each of
>   the above.**

cases:

1. Returning **false** from an inline event handler prevents the browser from navigating to the link address, but it doesn't stop the event from propagating through the DOM.
2. Returning **false** from a jQuery event handler prevents the browser from navigating to the link address and it stops the event from propagating through the DOM.
3. Returning **false** from a regular DOM event handler does absolutely nothing.

Will see all three example.

1. Inline return false.

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='https://stackoverflow.com' onclick='return false'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  var link = document.querySelector('a');

  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event prevented using inline html'
    alert('Link Clicked');
  });


  function executeParent() {
    alert('Div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

2. Returning **false** from a jQuery event handler.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  $('a').click(function(event) {
    alert('Link Clicked');
    $('a').text('Click event prevented using return FALSE');
    $('a').contents().unwrap();
    return false;
  });
  $('div').click(function(event) {
    alert('Div clicked');
  });
</script>
```

3. Returning false from a regular DOM event handler.

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='https://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event prevented'
    alert('Link Clicked');
    return false
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('Div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

Hope these examples are clear. Try executing all these examples in a html file to see how they work.

Comment: "Note that this behaviour differs from normal (non-jQuery) event handlers,"  This is a surprising and confusing thing to say, at this point, since the material in the answer before this point doesn't seem to be talking about jQuery at all.

Answer (score 24):

This is the quote from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-events)

**Event.preventDefault**

The preventDefault method prevents an event from carrying out its default functionality.  For example, you would use preventDefault on an A element to stop clicking that element from leaving the current page:

```
//clicking the link will *not* allow the user to leave the page 
myChildElement.onclick = function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log('brick me!'); 
};

//clicking the parent node will run the following console statement because event propagation occurs
logo.parentNode.onclick = function(e) { 
    console.log('you bricked my child!'); 
};
```

While the element's default functionality is bricked, the event continues to bubble up the DOM.

**Event.stopPropagation**

The second method, stopPropagation, allows the event's default functionality to happen but prevents the event from propagating:

```
//clicking the element will allow the default action to occur but propagation will be stopped...
myChildElement.onclick = function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('prop stop! no bubbles!'); 
};

//since propagation was stopped by the child element's onClick, this message will never be seen!
myChildElement.parentNode.onclick = function(e) { 
    console.log('you will never see this message!'); 
};
```

stopPropagation effectively stops parent elements from knowing about a given event on its child.

> While a simple stop  method allows us to quickly handle events, it's
>   important to think about what exactly you want to happen with
>   bubbling.  I'd bet that all a developer really wants is preventDefault
>   90% of the time!  Incorrectly "stopping" an event could cause you
>   numerous troubles down the line; your plugins may not work and your
>   third party plugins could be bricked.  Or worse yet -- your code
>   breaks other functionality on a site.

Answer (score 21):

> ***event.preventDefault()***
> Prevents the browsers default behaviour (such as opening a link), but does not stop the event from bubbling up the DOM.
>
> ***event.stopPropagation()***
> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM, but does not stop the browsers default behaviour.
>
> ***return false;***
> Usually seen in jQuery code, it prevents the browsers default behaviour, prevents the event from bubbling up the
> DOM, and immediately Returns from any callback.

Check out this [really nice & easy 4 min read](https://medium.com/@jacobwarduk/how-to-correctly-use-preventdefault-stoppropagation-or-return-false-on-events-6c4e3f31aedb) with examples from where the above piece was taken.

Answer (score 5):

`event.preventDefault();` Stops the default action of an element from happening.

`event.stopPropagation();` Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

For example, if there is a link with a click method attached inside of a `DIV` or `FORM` that also has a click method attached, it will prevent the `DIV` or `FORM` click method from firing.

Answer (score 5):

Event.preventDefault- stops browser default behaviour. Now comes what is browser default behaviour. Assume you have a anchor tag and it has got a href attribute and this anchor tag is nested inside a div tag which has got a click event. Default behaviour of anchor tag is when clicked on the anchor tag it should navigate, but what event.preventDefault does is it stops the navigation in this case. But it never stops the bubbling of event or escalation of event i.e

```
<div class="container">
 <a href="#" class="element">Click Me!</a>
</div>

$('.container').on('click', function(e) {
 console.log('container was clicked');
});

$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Now link won't go anywhere
  console.log('element was clicked');
});
```

The result will be

"element was clicked"

"container was clicked"

Now event.StopPropation it stops bubbling of event or escalation of event. Now with above example

```
$('.container').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('container was clicked');
});

$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Now link won't go anywhere
  e.stopPropagation(); // Now the event won't bubble up
 console.log('element was clicked');
});
```

Result will be

"element was clicked"

For more info refer this link 
https://codeplanet.io/preventdefault-vs-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation/

Answer (score 2):

Both `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` are methods available on the event object in JavaScript, but they serve different purposes when handling events. Here's a brief explanation of their differences:

1. `event.stopPropagation()`: This method is used to stop the event from propagating (bubbling) up or down the DOM hierarchy. Events in JavaScript can bubble up from a target element to its ancestors, or they can be captured as they come down the DOM hierarchy. When you use `event.stopPropagation()`, it prevents the event from reaching any other event listeners on the parent or ancestor elements. However, it does not prevent the default action associated with the event.

Example use case: You have a click event listener on a button inside a collapsible menu. You also have another click event listener on the body element that collapses the menu when you click outside of it. By using `event.stopPropagation()` on the button click event, you prevent the event from reaching the body click event listener, thus stopping the menu from collapsing when the button is clicked.

2. `event.preventDefault()`: This method is used to prevent the browser's default behavior associated with the event. It does not affect the bubbling or capturing of the event itself. Calling this method informs the browser that you want to handle the event explicitly and override its default action.

Example use case: You have a form with a submit button, and you want to validate the form via JavaScript before submitting it. In a submit event listener, you can use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from being submitted to the server until your validation logic is executed and the form passes validation.

In conclusion, `event.stopPropagation()` is used to stop event propagation, while `event.preventDefault()` is used to prevent the default behavior associated with the event. They can be used independently or together depending on your specific event handling requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Lets compare `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`

All of these can be used in event handler functions.

> **`event.preventDefault()`** prevents the default browser behavior for a given element. In `form` element it prevents form submitting and for `href` element it prevents navigating.

> **`event.stopPropagation()`** stops an event from bubbling or propagating up the DOM tree.

Whereas,

> **`return false`** is a combination of both preventDefault() and stopPropagation().

Answer (score -4):

```js
$("#but").click(function(event){
console.log("hello");
  event.preventDefault();
 });


$("#foo").click(function(){
 alert("parent click event fired !");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <button id="but">button</button>
</div>
```