# Can I exclude a button click inside a TR click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently highlighting a table row when selected but in one of the cells I have a button. When I click the button I am triggering the table row click event.  Is it possible to separate the two?

My two calls currently look like this:

```
$('table.table-striped tbody tr').on('click', function () {
   $(this).find('td').toggleClass('row_highlight_css');
}); 


$(".email-user").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Button Clicked");
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col-1</th>
      <th>col-2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Data</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-mini btn-success email-user" id="email_123" type="button">Email User</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea how I might stop the button click event from triggering the row click event?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to use `stopPropagation`:

```
$(".email-user").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("Button Clicked");
});
```

(See also : [What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault))

Comment: That was it.  Thanks also for the link, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by event bubbling, try using `e.stopPropagation();` just after `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('.table-striped').find('tr').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('td').toggleClass('row_highlight_css');
});

$(".email-user").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```