# Prevent default action of opening keypad on iOS 5.1

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, ios5

I built my site with phonegap.
When the keypad appeared the whole content of the page slid up.
How can I prevent the default action of opening the keypad on iOS 5.1.1 ?

Comment: try event.preventDefault()

Comment: i tried it,but not work.

Comment: What user action is triggering the keypad to appear? Is the problem that the content moves up when the keypad appears, or is the problem that the content does not go back down to where it was after the keyboard disappears?

Comment: The problem that the content moves up when the keypad appears,what can i do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure, that you can t prevent this behaviour.

At Android it can be configured, but it does not work really good if you do some fancy CSS.

If the content won t slide up, the keyboard may hide the entered text.

If you set an input element to readonly, the keyboard will not be triggered. May be you can disable the input an enable it after the page is loaded completely.

Answer (score 1):

I read a question like that but old, and there are some pretty code you can try

`stopPropagation() , preventDefault()`
the deference is 
`stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.

`preventDefault` prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

also there are a variable you can set to true

```
e = window.event;
e.cancelBubble = true;
```

there are some useful links in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

I hope this useful for you.