# jQuery mousewheel stop propagation

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, jquery-events

How to stop propagation with the mousewheel event listener?

When using the mousewheel over the `content` element the whole document is scrolling too.

This doesn't work:

```
content.on('mousewheel', function(e, delta){
    content.scrollTop(content.scrollTop() - (40 * delta));
    set_bar();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

## solution

```
content.on('mousewheel', function(e, delta){
    content.scrollTop(content.scrollTop() - (40 * delta));
    set_bar();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: AWESOME! I set stopPropagation and then returned false. Any drawbacks you know of, by returning false? I had no trouble but I vaguely remember reading dire warnings about this before.

Comment: It might help if you move the solution down to the answer then marked it as resolved.  That way it doesn't show up in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confusing stopPropgation and preventDefault.

- `stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.
- `preventDefault` prevents the default action happening on the
  element. In this case it will prevent scrolling, for a click event on
  an anchor for instance it will stop the link taking you to the URL
  defined in the href attribute.
- `return false` on the other hand does both of these things.

Its an important distinction to make as you might want to use event bubbling for event delegation while preventing the default action at the same time.

See these two posts for more information:

[**Difference between preventDefault and return false**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

[**Difference between preventDefault and stopPropagation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Answer (score 3):

The original solution is ***very close***.
Here's what worked:

```
    $(".myScrollableDiv").on("mousewheel",function(e) {
        var scrollRate = 100;
        var $t = $(this);
        var dy = e.originalEvent.deltaY * scrollRate;
        $t.scrollTop($t.scrollTop() + dy);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I think the main reason is that jQuery doesn't give us a second parameter (delta) but it can be found in the event itself.  Otherwise it's fine.