# event.preventDefault vs event.stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault, stoppropagation

Can someone explain what's the difference between `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`?

I have a table and within that table I have an img tag.

When I click the img tag, I want to see a popup.

But I also want to stop the selection of multiple rows, so I use:

```
$("table.items tbody tr").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

When I use the js code, the popup does not appear;

If I delete the js code, the popup works.

```
$(".info").live("click",function(e){
    //console.log('ok');
    e.stopPropagation();
    var elem = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("image_","container_");
    $('#'+id).toggle(100, function() {
        if($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "$url",
                data: { document_id:elem.attr('document_id') },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#'+id).html(data);
                }
            });
            }
        });
});
```

Why?

Comment: This will help you http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-events

Comment: Please show your html structure so we know where the image is with relation to the table structure

Comment: It's too late to stop the selection on `click`; use `mousedown`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I am not a Javascript expert but as far as I know:

`stopPropagation` is used to make sure the event doesn't bubble up the chain. eg. a click on a `<td>` tag would also fire click events on it's parent `<tr>`, and then its parent `<table>`, etc. `stopPropagation` prevents this from happening.

`preventDefault` is used to stop the normal action of an element, eg. `preventDefault` in a click handler on a link would stop the link being followed, or on a submit button would stop the form being submitted.

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano your comment makes no sense.  sevenseacat's answer looks 100% correct to me and can be checked with the answers on the [dup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault) as well as with the jQuery documentation for [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) and [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

Comment: does stopPropagation also stop the capture phase?

Comment: I think the confusion around these two functions (three if you count `stopImmediatePropagation`) is a doubt about whether stopping propagation automatically prevents default too. It seems like it might.

Answer (score 9):

- `stopPropagation` on a *child* will stop that event from happening on the 
  *parent* (the entire ancestors)
- `preventDefault` on a *child* will stop the event on the child but it
  will happen on it's *parent* (and the ancestors too!)

Now in your code which is the parent? which is the child? `img` is child `tr` is parent(well grandparent to be honest), So guess where the `stopPropagation` code should be.

Comment: I get the impression this is wrong. I think stopPropagation DOES NOT stop the action of the child from happening?

Comment: You're probably talking about preventDefault, but my comment was aimed at the stopPropagation explanation. User rps has corrected his answer after my comment.

Comment: @Trisped, 

@user1884155 is right, the example you're saying seems to be of `preventDefault`'s. 

And initially I made the mistake of saying that the `stopPropagation` will stop any child's events too which was later corrected by @user1884155.

Comment: @user1884155 Sorry, copy paste error.  Should have been `preventDefault` as you said.

Answer (score 8):

Event [`preventDefault` From W3C:](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

> The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an
>   element from happening.
>   For example:
>
> Prevent a submit button from submitting a form Prevent a link from
>   following the URL

Event [`stopPropagation` From W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp):

> The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to
>   parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being
>   executed.