# understanding event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

As an exercise, I'm trying to add an event listener to an ebay.com element.

Expected result: show an alert and stop the web page from going to the next URL.

What happens: the alert is shown but the next URL is shown anyway.

I found something interesting on the product pages where I'm testing out `preventDefault`, `stopPropagtion` and `stopImmediatePropagation`.

No matter which combinations I use, nothing seem to work.

The basic code is:

```
$('#binBtn_btn').click(function(evt){
    alert('hi');
    evt.stopPropagation(); //or any other option.
});
```

The thing is that I get the alert, but it still goes to the next page, as if I never stopped the propagation.

I read a lot of articles about event handling, but I couldn't find the answer.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does the element look like?

Comment: It's an add to cart button.

Comment: How about you create an example of your problem first in a JSFiddle. Trying to attach events on random sites isn't a productive way to understand Events in JavaScript.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147242/event-preventdefault-vs-event-stoppropagation

Comment: @vcrzy it's not the same question... 
these are different things. If you would try doing what it says there, you won't be able to stop their functionality. I suggest you look at dave salomon's answer below. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess it that the Button has its own click handler, and it's firing before yours.

`$('#binBtn_btn').data("events")`  shows us that there is indeed a `click` event. Remove that using [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

```
$('#binBtn_btn').off('click');
```

Clicking the button now will still cause the form the submit, as all we're doing is browsing to a page. The button is actually just an `a` tag.

```
$('#binBtn_btn').click(function(e){
    alert('Gotcha!');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Let's see what happens if we remove *their* handler, add ours, and then *re-add* their one...

```
var existing = $('#binBtn_btn').data('events').click[0];
$('#binBtn_btn').off('click');
$('#binBtn_btn').click(function(e){ alert('foo'); e.stopImmediatePropagation(); return false; });
$('#binBtn_btn').data('events').click.push(existing);
```

Same, but just looking at the function for the click handler (rather than tweaking the `events.click` array directly...)

```
var existing = $('#binBtn_btn').data('events').click[0].handler;
$('#binBtn_btn').off('click');
$('#binBtn_btn').click(function(e){ alert('foo'); e.stopImmediatePropagation(); e.preventDefault(); });
$('#binBtn_btn').click(existing);
```

As expected, what is now the second handler -- their handler -- doesn't first. (I've added a `return false;` rather than `e.preventDefault();`, just to demonstrate different ways of doing things!)

You can check out what they're doing by placing a breakpoint and viewing the `existing` var above. You'll see that at the end of their function, they do indeed call `e.preventDefault();`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's still something that is unclear.
Maybe you can clarify that for me. 
According to my understanding, e.stopImmediatePropagation(); should, well, stop immediate propagation. so basically, if my alert is fired, it's not suppose to fire anything else. Can you help me with an explanation?
Thanks.

Comment: @alex No worries. I believe this is due to the ordering of the click handlers. The first one is firing before yours can get to `stopImmediatePropagation();`. I've updated my answer with a test, which shows this is likely to be the case. If your one fires first, the existing one doesn't fire (if we add it back AFTER your one.)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. You've been a great help. One more question please - regarding your last paragraph. How did you manage to break on their code and how did you got to see their function?

Comment: @alex, I've set up a blog, and my [first post](http://davesalomon.com/blog/2014/11/09/basic-debugging/) is specially to talk about this. It's bascally F12, viewing the event handlers on the element (well, object), and digging through there. Thanks!

Comment: I kept trying this thing on other sites and I found that this method doesn't work on a site like flipkart.com. There, for example, an input element is used, and everything is processed in AJAX. When I use $().data('events') i get undefined. why is that?

Comment: `.data("events")` was removed in jQuery 1.8. You'll probably find them in `$._data($(elem), 'events');`. It work's on eBay 'cos they're using an old version.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work on a site like flipkart?
Cause there it's a different mechanism.

Comment: `$('.btn-buy-now').click(function(e){ alert('foo'); return false; });` works for http://www.flipkart.com/huawei-honor-t1/p/itmdzvf2cgvghuat?pid=TABDZVBFP9CFGB6K . Based on the fact that there's no click handlers present, you can just injector your own without worry. `return false;` will prevent the form being submitted. (As would `e.preventDefault();`)

Answer (score 1):

try using `evt.preventDefault()` like this:

```
$('#binBtn_btn').click(function(evt){ 

    evt.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');  

});
```

Then it will not go to the next page.

Comment: As mentioned, I tried stopPropogation, preventDefault & stopImmidiatePropogation in different variations, nothing worked

Comment: you sure you are using it in <a> tag? Then probably close your browser and then restart. Sometimes these issues will arises due to browser caching.

Comment: Then `#binBtn_btn` propably is not the id of your `<a>`? Please provide the html markup.

Comment: just have a look at Dave's answer above.