# jQuery e.stopPropagation Conflict With body onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap dropdown menu. To make it keep on show on click inside dropdown then I set it to JavaScript like this

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e)
{
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It works. Then now I have

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
     $('body').on("click",'#btn_post',function(e)
     {
          alert("waw");
     }
});

<button class="btn btn-default" id="btn_post">Click</button>
```

When I click button, I can't see the alert "waw". But when I remove the `e.stopPropagation();` the alert will appear.

I want that 2 function can be run without conflict.

Comment: If this is *really* your code, the function for the button isn't closed properly.

Comment: @Scott let me know where?

Comment: `$('body').on("click",'#btn_post',function(e)  { alert("waw");   });` You are missing a closing parenthesis and a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `stopPropagation` use `preventDefault` it might fix your problem.

`stopPropagation` is used to make sure the event doesn't bubble up the chain. eg. a click on a `<td>` tag would also fire click events on it's parent `<tr>`, and then its parent `<table>`, etc. `stopPropagation` prevents this from happening.

`preventDefault` is used to stop the normal action of an element, eg. `preventDefault` in a click handler on a link would stop the link being followed, or on a submit button would stop the form being submitted.

for more detail [event.preventDefault vs event.stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147242/event-preventdefault-vs-event-stoppropagation)