# bootstrap 3, collapse button in <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a collapsed menu, but the menu should open by clicking on the arrow.

arrow in tag a,
how to stop following a link, if click on the arrow?

```
<ul id="menu_0" class="nav nav-stacked">
<li><a href="http://example.org">item<span class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" type="button" data-parent="#menu_0" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu_submenu_1"></i></span></a>
    <ul id="menu_submenu_1" class="nav nav-stacked collapse">
        <li><a href="http://example.org">subitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.org">subitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.org">subitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.org">subitem 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

i trying this, but no effects

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu_0 .pull-right').click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation();});
});
```

Comment: try event.preventDefault();

Comment: as per your comment I've placed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/preventdefault/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu_0 .pull-right').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault();});
});
```

[difference between preventDefault and stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)