# jQuery/JS stop propogation after button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am posting data from user to php script and displaying response as a result.

Issue with me is after I click button it reload the page and empty all textbox without displaying reply from server script.

I tried with `event.stopPropagation();` and `resturn false` but still no help.

HTML  :

```
 <div class="show" id="show"></div>
```

JS:

```
    $( "#submit" ).click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            //var cat = $("#cats option:selected").html();
            var post = document.getElementById("post").value;
            var tag = document.getElementById("tags").value;
            dataInsert(post,tag);
            return false;
    });

    function dataInsert(post,tag)
    {               
        var xmlhttp;
        alert("hi");
        show.innerHTML = '';
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }           
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            //document.getElementById("old-records").innerHTML = "";                
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var div2 = document.getElementById("show");
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                div2.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }       
        xmlhttp.open("POST","koove_getTag_db.php",true);                
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send('post=' + post + '&tag=' + tag ) ;         
        alert(post+cat+tag);
    }
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you doing the longhand, plain vanilla JavaScript AJAX request?

Comment: you want `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up to parent elements, also note that if your code errors out before reaching `return false` the default event action will not be prevented

Comment: If you're using a `a` tag, then you need `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: There is more than one way to submit a form. You should not rely on the user clicking a button. Use `$('#theform').submit(function(){})`

Comment: `$('#theform').submit(function(e){e.preventDefault(); ... });`

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 event.preventDefault()
```

instead of this

```
 event.stopPropagation()
```

Difference between thses 2 methods : Read here - [What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

"**stopPropagation** stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.

**preventDefault** prevents the default action the browser makes on that event."

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation to this answer. Why do you think it works? What does it do?