# preventDefault but activate links

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my navigation menu, I have a dropdown that I want to use. The actual dropping down is fine, and I've prevented the automatic bubbling by using `preventDefault();` but now all the links within the dropdown no longer work.

How do I make it so that the dropdown works, doesn't bubble and all the links within the dropdown work?

Edit: I've also used `event.stopPropagation()` to no effect either. What's going on here?!

This is my code:

```
// Toggle dropdowns
$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: `preventDefault !== stopPropagation`

Comment: More info on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop bubbling, use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation).

Only use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) to prevent the default action of the event from happening.

---

Ah, now I see your problem. The issue is that when clicking a menu item to open a submenu, since the item is an anchor pointing to `#`, the document will scroll to top.

To avoid that, I suggest getting rid of `href="#"`.

Alternatively, you can use `preventDefault` only if the clicked element was that element, not a descendant:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function(e){
    if(this == e.target) e.stopPropagation();
    // ...
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KQF9Z/4/)

Comment: Unfortunately using stopPropagation() doesn't stop the snapping to the top of the screen. It does activate the links though

Comment: @patkay Can you post a fiddle showing that behavior?

Comment: it's a bit hodgepodge, but hopefully it's enough for you to look at. http://jsfiddle.net/KQF9Z/

Comment: @patkay So you want to load a new page, but leave the dropdown opened?

Comment: Yes, when you open the drop down, you get the options, click on one of the options and it takes you to the new page with the dropdown closed and reset

Comment: if you expand the window and make the nav load full width, if you scroll down the page and press 'Services', the page will jump back to the top

Comment: which part did you change?

Comment: Oh my, how could I be so silly?! 

Thank you so much for your patience! You're a legend. =) @Oriol

Answer (score 0):

You can check which element was clicked by using e.target, and if the clicked element was a sub menu link, don't preventDefault

Comment: sorry, Im a bit of a jquery newb. How would I go about this? Can you show me some example code?

Comment: no problem. this is rough but will give you an idea of what you need to do  
  

    $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e){
        //check to see if the clicked item doesn’t has a parent ul with a calls of sub-menu   
        if (!($(e.target).parents('ul').hasClass('sub-menu’))) {    
          e.preventDefaul();  
       $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggleClass('open');  
      }  
    });  
  
  
  
excuse the formatting, can’t get stack overflow to allow formatting