# Prevent custom event from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent custom event on parent when child is clicked. Note that I don't have access to the code of parent event. I've tried doing `e.preventDefault()` on the button itself but it doesn't help.

Is there any way of ignoring all parent events when something inside of it is clicked?

```js
$(function(){
  // Note that this is just an example, I don't have access to this code
  // This is some custom event inside custom plugin
  $('.container').on('click', function() {
    alert('This should be alerted only if you click on green box');
  });
  
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    // Here I want to make sure that *parent* events are not triggered.
    alert('Button is triggered, green box should be not triggered');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

Comment: as mentioned by imelgrat, event.stopProgation should work for jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use the `event.stopPropagation()` method. The `event.stopPropagation()` method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed. You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/imelgrat/q2beoazn/)

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#button").click(function (event) {
           alert("This is the button.");
           // Comment the following to see the difference
           event.stopPropagation();
       });

       $("#outerdiv").click(function (event) {
           alert("This is the outer div.");
       });
   });
```

In this simple example, if you click on the button, the event is handled by its own handler and it won't bubble up the DOM hierarchy. You can add a very simple handler calling `event.stopPropagation()` on the button and it won't bubble up. No need to mess with the parent's JS.