# How to check preconditions with Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal that is working correctly, being triggered by a button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info mm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mm_modal" data-req="foo">
```

This modal works with some data from a form. I would like to display an alert and not display the modal at all, if the form data fails validation. How do I do this?

I have tried adding a function:

```
$('button.mm').click( function(ev)
{
    var req = $(ev.currentTarget).data('req');
    if ( req === 'foo' )
    {
        alert('Foo not supported'); 
        throw new Error('Foo not supported');
    }
}
```

The alert displays correctly but the `throw` does not seem to abort execution; the Bootstrap modal goes on to be displayed anyway.

Comment: Hmm interesting way to do that, have you tried `ev.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: @FadiObaji Didn't work -- however doing `ev.preventDefault()` inside the `$('#mm_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(ev) {` function did work! So I'll move my logic into there. I originally wanted to have it in there but couldn't see how to prevent the modal there either, so I figured having the logic in the click handler would make things easier... apparently not. if you post that as an answer I'll accept

Comment: ok, give me few minutes to write it :)

Comment: I found the solution, don't change anything, i'll write the answer now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution (Tested and working):

Use `ev.stopPropagation();` instead of the `throw new Error('Foo not supported');` and the modal won't show.

**NOTE** using `ev.preventDefault();` won't stop the modal from appearing.

The difference between `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Hope that helps.