# Stop propagation to appended element

Tags: jquery, html

I append `<a>` tag to my `div` :

```
$('<a class="dz-jcrop" href="http://www.google.com"  >google</a>').appendTo('.dz-image-preview');
```

I want to stop propagation for `<a>` tag .. but when I try just to select the element I can't. I use the following code to log to test if my element is selected :

```
$(document).on('click', '.dz-jcrop', function(){ 
    console.log('me');
});
```

It doesn't get logged and the element is not selected. How to stop propagation to appended element?

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vkbrnzcm/)**

Comment: Can i stop propagation with writing code inside balise a ?

Comment: You mean you want to stop `defaultaction` of anchor?

Comment: For example i have <a href="x"></a> i want to redirect to 'x' but when i click an other action is launched then i'm redirected to x .. i want just to redirect to x

Comment: I fixed some typos and reworded the question and title for better readability. Please add your comments to the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/6sjzada9/

Use return false;

```
$('<a class="dz-jcrop" href="http://www.google.com"  >google</a>').appendTo('.dz-image-preview');
$(document).on('click', '.dz-jcrop', function(event){
    console.log('me');
    return false;
});
```

what is different between return and stopPropagation
See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30475572/4696809