# Event stopPropagation to close browse picture window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm trying to show a popup by append a balise like this :

```
$('<a id="dz-jcrop" class="dz-jcrop" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" >Crop image</a>').appendTo('.dz-image-preview');
```

The popup is showned but before the browse window to find picture is opened like this :

[image]

I try to stop propagation to open popup without show the browse picture window .. but it is also showned :

```
$(document).on('click', '.dz-jcrop', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('me');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop propagation to appended element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981270/stop-propagation-to-appended-element)