# Submitting post form via ajax, browser poup

Tags: javascript, wordpress, coffeescript

I'm trying to submit my classic post content form via javascript like this. I want to just publish/update wp post but from different button then classic wp-publish box.

```
publishPost: ->
    $('.tome-publish').click ->
        $('form#post').submit()

        location = window.location.href;
        location += ( location.indexOf( '?' ) != -1 ) ? '&' : '?';
        location += 'wp-post-new-reload=true';
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, location );
        console.log( window.history );
```

but whe the forms submit browser asks me

```
The changes you made will be lost if you navigate away from this page.

Are you sure you want to leave this page?
```

do you know what to do to get rid of this javascript nag? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

when you use .submit() its synchronous form submit it is same as normal form submit. if you want to do an ajax post use $.ajax instead

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to know for sure without seeing more of your code, but I wonder if you're allowing other listeners to process the `click` event after you handle it in your listener.  Here's a [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault) talking about `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` which might come in handy here.

Comment: just updated post so you can see whole functions, thank you for the links.