# DataTable How to prevent row click in columns containing hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am dealing with a javascript datatable with clickable rows. Each row when clicked forwards the browser to a different page. 
A column of the row contains a hyperlink. When the hyperlin is clicked I don't want the row click event to be fired or managed.

Here is how I have implemented the row click event

```
    $(tableId+' tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
           window.location.href = $(this).attr('url');
    });
```

Comment: Please provide the html

Comment: How about using css `pointer-events:none;` or jquery `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Can you check my answer ?

Comment: You need to set `event.stopPropagation()` for the `click` event type on the `td` which contains the `href` (hyperlink).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add an event listener to a parent, the event by default "bubbles" downwards and attaches the event to all children. So in this case you setting the event on `tr` (parent) and the event will bubble down and attach itself to the `td` (children). So one of these `td` from what I understand contains your `href` (hyperlink) and so to block the `click` event which originally was set on the parent, you have to set another event listener specifically of the [event type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) `click` within the function for this event you simply need state `event.stopPropagation()` and it will override the `tr` click event which bubbled down.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    //SET EVENT ON PARENT(TR), EVENT BUBBLES BY DEFAULT DOWNWARDS THEREFORE TD's WILL INHERIT
    document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click',()=>window.location.href = "wherever"); 

    //ADDING ANOTHER EVENT LISTENER OF THE SAME TYPE (CLICK) WHICH BLOCKS THE BUBBLING PROPOGATION DOWNARDS
    document.getElementById('myhyperlink').addEventListener('click',(e)=>event.stopPropagation());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent clicking on anchor from redirecting a page, you have to simply catch the click event and disable it's default behaviour.

```
$("table td a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

You have to just prevent default behaviour, if you would also stop propagation of event, your other event listener wouldn't get called. See more info here: [What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

If your goal is to disable redirect of anchor links only when the javascript is enabled, **another solution** might be to set `onclick` attribute that would disable default redirect. However, this seems not to work in webkit based browsers.

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="javascript:return false;">and example</a>
```

[Here is jsFiddle with example](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/7w6p06fd/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()`

```
$(tableId+' tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('url');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write code following ways:

```
$(tableId+' tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     window.location.href = $(this).attr('url');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to disable row click for that particular column

```
$('tableId+' tbody'').on('click', 'td', function () {

         if ($(this).index() == 4 ) { // provide index of your column in which you prevent row click here is column of 4 index
             return;
         }

            // you can do additional functionality by clicking on this column here                         
    });
```