# Overlapping events from different elements double fire the same function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events, jquery-events

I have a dead simple search form:

```
<div>
  <input id="searchArea" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your search terms">
  <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
</div>
```

and a snippet of Javascript controlling it:

```
function searchFunction() {
  console.log("This is a POST request being send to the server");
}

$("#searchButton").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  searchFunction();  
})

$("#searchArea").on("change", function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault();
  searchFunction();
});
```

The problem is that click and change overlap in functionality and so I get the following:

**When I type something in the text box and then click elsewhere in the screen, `searchFunction` is fired properly but if "elsewhere" becomes the search button, then `searchFunction` double fires.**

My question is this: Once inside the `click` handler, is there any way to cancel the `change` handler from firing as well which would otherwise cause `searchFunction` to double fire?

Mind that `searchArea` and `searchButton` don't have a parent-child relationship which means conventional methods like `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` won't work.

You can see it in action in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/konos5/86a3ufnw/31/).

Comment: a simple debounce would solve this, and should be used regardless since this is an ajax request based on user input events.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

Comment: @KevinB what's a simple debounce?

Comment: google debounce. the first 4 results i see (w3schools being blocked) have pretty good explanations and examples.

Comment: @KevinB Yes. The debounce function will indeed work. However, it is but a mere workaround "hacked" for this case. Is there a more "proper" way to deal with this issue?

Comment: how is that a hacked workaround? it simply delays the request from happening to prevent 50 requests being sent when the user clicks the button 50 times in a row. It's a very common technique for this sort of thing and not at all a "hack"

Comment: @KevinB In the scenario you mention it's not because you prevent the mindless user from doing "harm". However using debounce to camouflage erroneous programming constructs (like mine) may not be the best way to go.

Comment: just curious why you're not using keyup or input event for `#searchArea`

Comment: @yezzz traffic throttling...

Comment: @kstratis heh, and that's what a debounce is for. so not only will you get a more responsive form, you'll prevent the user from accidentally spamming your server.

Comment: @kstratis: Understood. And the change event was added for better UX? Also, what about blur event on the input, allowing to use relatedTarget: https://jsfiddle.net/kd2nm9db/

Comment: @Kevin B: thanks for the insight about debouncing