# How to prevent defaut behaviour of "input submit"?

Tags: javascript

I have an input submit, after attaching an onclick handler on it, what's the standard way to prevent a post request to "form action=xxx" url? Is it "return false", or "e.preventDefault", or "e.stopPropogation"?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Either `return false` or `preventDefault` should be sufficient.

Comment: See [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) and [What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call preventDefault() like this

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();  

  // DO SOMETHING
});
```

Comment: why is it in the beginning and not the end?

Comment: it is up to you, but put it in the beginning may be better if your code if too long or may contain promise or callback