# Item with toggle and href link

Tags: ionic-framework, toggle, href

I have a list with items and each item has a toggle and href link, the problem is when click to the toggle the href linked fired and then I moved to the second page, how I can resolve this problem:

```
<ion-list  ng-repeat="(key,value) in checkload | groupBy:'Niveau'">
  <div class="item item-divider" >{{key}}</div>
  <ion-item href="/#/detailCheckArrivee/{{checkarrivee.ficheDeMission.id}}/{{var.id}}" on-swipe-left="warn(checkarrivee.ficheDeMission.id,var.id)" ng-repeat="var in value" >

    <ion-toggle class="noToggleBorder"  ng-class="{item:checkarrivee.ficheDeMission==undefined,'item':checkarrivee.ficheDeMission==undefined}"   ng-model='checkarrivee.boo[var.id]'  ng-click="checkarrivee.isMissionSelected(var.id,checkarrivee.ficheDeMission.id)" toggle-class="toggle-positive">{{var.designation}}</ion-toggle>
    <button  class="button button-clear icon ion-star button-assertive"
            ng-click="toggleStar(var)" ng-show="var.star">
    </button>
    <ion-option-button class="button-{{option}}">
      <i class="icon {{type}}"></i>
    </ion-option-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: I do not understand what is your problem?

Comment: my proble is...i have to events in the item, there are the toggle event and the link event ..and when i clic into the toggle it doesnt fired..the link fired instead

Comment: Not sure am I getting this right but do you have an onClick in an onClick - if this is true take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault