# Rails delete link works a bit too much, why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bootbox

I am trying to prettify the confirmation dialog that browser pops when pressing on rails' delete links, with [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/), so I have modified the delete link's code as follow

### .html.erb

```
<%= link_to '#', :class => "btn btn-danger delete-link", 'data-src' => item_path(@item), :method => :delete do %>
    <span class='fa fa-times'></span> Delete IT
<% end %>
```

### application.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete-link[data-method="delete"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('THIS SHOULD NOT REDIRECT!');
    });
});
```

But weirdly when I press the button the link actives and deletes the item! but also it logs the `THIS SHOULD NOT REDIRECT!` message too!

## Questions:

1. What is going on?
2. How can I get what I want (i.e disable the link activation so that I can activate it later by choice)?

---

P.S: I've also tried this

```
$('.delete-link[data-method="delete"]').unbind('click').click(function(e){...});
```

but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

so you're code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete-link[data-method="delete"]').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log('THIS SHOULD NOT REDIRECT!');
  });
});
```

- stopPropagation stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.
- preventDefault prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

Reference: [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault) has some extra details on these two events.