# event.preventDefault() on keydown isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to capture the key presses on a Bootstrap Tab Panel menus, but it just bubbles up ignoring the preventDefault() placed on the tabs's keydown handler.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  console.log("document catched the keydown event");

};

$('body > div > ul > li > a').on("keydown",function (e) {
  console.log("handled by the child - stop bubbling please");
  e.preventDefault();

});
```

Example:
http://www.bootply.com/xUlN0dLRaV

what am i missing here ?

Comment: e.stopPropagation()?

Comment: you need to use `stopPrepagation` as answered before, and this is obviously not a duplicate. our mate is asking why the function he used isn't working, not how it differs from another function.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try `e.stopPropagation()`

**`e.stopPropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree**, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('body > div > ul > li > a').on("keydown",function (e) {
  console.log("handled by the child - stop bubbling please");
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Difference?**

[What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Comment: When you determine a question is a duplicate, rather than answering it, post a comment saying it's a duplicate so people can close it correctly. (And of course, in about 1400 points of rep, you'll be able to cast close votes directly.)

Answer (score 1):

Besides `e.preventDefault` you have to also use `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent event bubling up. In your case you can also return `false` from event handler which do both:

```
$('body > div > ul > li > a').on("keydown",function (e) {
  console.log("handled by the child - stop bubbling please");
  return false;
});
```