# window.blur - Alert box keeps showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show an alert box when browser loses focus. So here is my code:

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    alert("Your browser lost focus");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

However, the alert box keep pop up, say when I use Alt+Tab to switch to another window. Can anyone help telling me what is wrong?

Comment: are you looking for `e.preventDefault()?` to prevent default action

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

Answer (score 4):

Using `$(window).blur` - Once an `alert` window pops, the `alert` box **itself** is causing you to lose focus on your browser. This is **highly unrecommended**.

If you only want to test lose focus, you should use:

```
 console.log("Your browser lost focus");
```

Otherwise, do not expose this to the site users - it will cause an infinite loop of `alert` windows.

Comment: ProTip: Get out of the habit of using `alert()` for debugging. You'll find `console.log()` and `console.error()` will make your life much better. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$('selector').on(eventType, function (event) {
  alert(('cancelable' in event));   //will return true
  alert(event.cancelable);      //will return true if event can be cancelled
  //NOTE: Firefox mistakenly always returns true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TRY THIS DEMO, ALERT ON LOST FOCUS, WHEN LOST FOCUS TRIGGER OR CALL ANY ACTION
```

[TRY THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alfinpaul/whQFz/341/)