# clicking on icon inside button of materialize-css react triggers onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, materialize

Clicking on the button triggers the onClick appropriately but clicking on the icon within the button triggers the onClick as well but without the right data (`item.target.className` and what not)

```
<button id={check} onClick={this.changeTimesButton} className="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i className="material-icons">check_box</i></button>
```

Is there anyway to disable the icon being able to be clicked

using materialize-css in react project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u cannot handle event.target in this.changeTimesButton(event) :

set onClick() on icon tag then prevent the default action

```
    <button id={check} onClick={this.changeTimesButton} 
      className="waves-effect waves-light btn">
      <i className="material-icons" onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault()}}>check_box</i>
    </button>
```

**UPDATE**

you can use ***stopPropagation*** instead of ***preventDefault***

for more details on stopPropagation and preventDefault see this :

[What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)