# jquery - how to prevent submit form continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, bootstrap-modal, form-submit

I have a form in modal as follows:

```
 <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
             </div>
             <form id="Myform" action="/action_page.php" method="get">
                First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
                Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
                <input type="button" onclick="submitform()" value="Submit">
             </form>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
   function submitform() {

        //try
        //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        //event.stopPropagation();

        //check validate is valid
        if (formValid) {
            $("#Myform").trigger("submit");
        }
    }

$("#Myform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         // e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $.ajax({
            type: this.method,
            cache: false,
            url: this.action,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                    $('#create-media').modal('toggle');

                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

        });
    });
```

Currently, when the user click on the submit button, the data will be sent to the server to process, during the time waiting for the results returned, the modal has not been closed, the user can click to submit more times. I do not want this to happen.
I want to prevent users submitting continuously, do not allow users to click on the second submit button, the user must wait for the results returned, if successful, the modal will be closed.
I was thinking of disabling the submit button, but that's not safe, because the user can enable that button because of javascript on the user machine.
I tried using event.stoppropagation () and event.stopimmediatepropagation () but it did not work.
Am I doing something wrong? How do I prevent users from submitting continuously?

Thanks AlL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follwing [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) idea, I would suggest you use a variable. However, instead of placing the variable at the beginning of the code, I would suggest to use the `beforeSend` callback provided by Ajax, it will be called right before sending the request.

```
var isBusy = false;
$("#Myform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(isBusy) {
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        cache: false,
        url: this.action,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            isBusy = true;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#create-media').modal('toggle');
            isBusy = false;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            isBusy = false;
        }

    });
});
```

You can learn more about the `beforeSend` callback [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
P.S. You could also use the `$.ajax.active` variable, which returns the amount of active ajax request, this might be a more elegent method.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `submitform` function a persistent `alreadySubmitted` variable. Also, try attaching the button handler from Javascript instead of HTML, and `preventDefault`:

```
const submitform = (() => {
  let alreadySubmitted = false;
  return (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (alreadySubmitted) return;
    alreadySubmitted = true;
    if (formValid) {
      $("#Myform").trigger("submit");
    }
  }
})();

document.querySelector('#Myform input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', submitForm);
```

Comment: I have also thought of this way, but my client they advised me to use event.stoppropagation ()
Is it possible to use event.stoppropagation () for this case?

Comment: stopprogation stops event from bubbling up to parent. I doubt it will work here

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Comment: As the javascript code above (I have commented at the moment), I tried to use it but it does not work, I do not know if I used it properly or not?

Comment: not every one uses es6 syntax, although its a good practice for future prove coding, we just are not there yet, therefore, its not good for someone else, especially for beginners