# bootstrap tab click preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, preventdefault, bootstrap-tabs

I am using bootstrap 3.3 and following the documents for tabs.

The simplest code given in the documentation is not working for me and I am unable to figure out why.

```
$('#mainTabs a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log('Clicked');
        });
```

When I use

```
show.bs.tab
```

event, preventDefault works. But for somereason click doesn't. The console is printing 'clicked', but does not prevent the tab change.

Basically I am trying to intercept the tab change, show a modal and based on user input, show or not show the new tab.

Please help.

Comment: Most probably the event doesn't propagate to the element you're matching, so there's no default there to prevent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `e.preventDefault();` is not working you must use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` instead.

For further information take a look at: [What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

```
$("#mainTabs a").click(function(e) {
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

If you've attached other event handlers to the link, you should look into `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` instead. Note that return false is equivalent to calling both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`.

## EDIT ==========

Use `return false;`.

Comment: yes this worked. Also I tried with return false and it too also worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: @StacyJ, Can you mark this answer, if you find this appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, for reasons unknown the prevent default does nothing to the bootstrap 4 form. Here's official code from bs team which has been slightly adjusted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('notificationForm');
            // Loop over them and prevent submission
            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                    if (!checkValidity()) {
                        console.log('did not validate');
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                    form.classList.add('was-validated');
                }, false);
            });
        }, false);
    })();
})
```

Then you need a `checkValidity` function which will return true or false depending on your validation.

**In case you're validating checkboxes:**

Chances are you're validating a group of checkmarks because that's not supported by bs so here's my validation code just in case (this will confirm that at least 1 checkboxes in the regionSelect div have been selected.

```
function checkValidity() {
    var regionsValidation = $('div.regionSelect :checkbox:checked').length;
    var categoriesValidation = $('div.categorySelect :checkbox:checked').length;
    if( (regionsValidation > 0) && (categoriesValidation > 0)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```