# How to avoid the default a href added by angular-ui-bootstrap in uib-tabset

Tags: refresh, angular-ui-bootstrap, href, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab, uib-tabset

How can I avoid the refresh caused by the default behavior of the tag a (link) auto added by uib-tabset using angular-ui-bootstrap?
Regards,
Nicolas

Comment: I tried stopPropagation() but it does not work

Comment: I found : http://embed.plnkr.co/f0p9uZgKuWTNh3Ss7okY

Comment: Solution can be: event.preventDefault();     But is it a good solution?

Comment: **Nobody** have a point of view regarding the use of preventDefault();? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this solution can be ok

```
event.preventDefault();
```