# How to prevent onclick event when dropdown's onChange?

Tags: javascript

How to prevent on click event when dropdown's onChange? Please find below code and its output.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr onclick="onClick()">
            <td>
                <select onchange="onChange()">
                    <option value='1'>One</option>
                    <option value='2'>Two</option>
                    <option value='3'>Three</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onClick() {
            console.log('on click event');
        }

        function onChange() {
            console.log('on change event')
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please find below console output on drop down selection

```
OUTPUT:

on click event
on change event
on click event
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this. You can put a check in your `onClick()` function to determine whether the click came from your select element:

```
function onClick(clickEvent) {
    const clickedElementType = clickEvent.target.nodeName;
    if (clickedElementType !== 'select') {
        console.log('on click event');
    }
}

//make sure we pass the event through from HTML
<tr onclick="onClick(event)">
```

Another way is to put an `onclick` handler on your `<select>` element and use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent it from bubbling up to the `<tr>` element:

```
 function onSelectClick(clickEvent) {
     clickEvent.stopPropagation(); //this event won't hit the other click handler
 }

 //HTML
 <select onchange="onChange()" onclick="onSelectClick(event)">
```

Comment: Your both solution is working.Thank you but Why  event.stopPropagation(); in code provided not working inside onchange(). can you clarify?

Comment: The `change` event is a different type of event from the `click` event, so you need to handle them separately (even though they both get fired at roughly the same time).

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two things to touch on events, `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.

On SO there is a clear explanation on what is the difference between the two, please have a look over [What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Anyway, as @duncan-thacker suggested before me, maybe you should think if that is the right place where to put your onClick event. You are forcing it to ignore the click on a child but you can avoid the issue if you try to use another html structure.