# row event fires before than event attached to element inside row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one event attached to on row click and one event attached to on checkbox change inside the row.

How to prevent that row click is fired first?

```js
$(document).on('click', 'table tr', function() {
  console.log('row');
})

$(document).on('change', 'table tr input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  console.log('chk');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the event you're handling on the inner element from `change` to `click`.

The `change` event doesn't fire until *after* the `click` event. The click event is triggered on the checkbox, then bubbles out to the row. When that completes, the change event is triggered on the checkbox.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'table tr', function() {
  console.log('row');
})

$(document).on('click', 'table tr input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  console.log('chk');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add click event for checkbox also to stop event propagation.please check this out for the hint.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54550360/3729024

Comment: He didn't say to prevent the even firing on the row, he just wants to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery selector `:not` to exclude checkbox for a tr click and then stop propagation of a child element event to the parent tr.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'table tr :not(input[type="checkbox"])', function(e) {
  console.log('row');
});

$(document).on('click', 'table tr input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
  console.log('chk');
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>another td</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```