# Overlap onClick() event an element inside a <td> table

Tags: jquery

I create a button within the `<td>` tag of a HTML table.

I've added a listener to trigger an alert on click event.

The `<td>` tag of the HTML table is equally tight to an event listener and triggers an alert with a distinct text from the button on click.

The snippet below illustrates the scenario above.

```js
$("#mytable").on("click", "td", function() {
    alert('this is td');
});  
   
$("#mybutton").on("click", function() {
    alert('this is button');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 20px">
            <span>table</span>
            <button style="margin: 5px; padding:5px; border: 1px solid black; float: right" id="mybutton"> display</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I effectively make the click event on the button execute without triggering the click event of the `<td>` tag in which the button is enclosed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stop the propagation of the click event after it has been consumed by a click on your button. This is done by a call to the **stopPropagation()** function on the event. Otherwise - as you experienced - the event will be propagated to the next element.

Here's an example:

```js
 $("#mytable").on("click", "td", function() {
     alert('this is td');
   });
   
   
 $("#mybutton").on("click", function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
     alert('this is button');
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
  <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 20px">test
  <button style="margin: 5px; padding:5px; border: 1px solid black; float: right" id="mybutton"> display</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @daniel8x Using this approach, you may find some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963669/4342563) very useful.

Answer (score -1):

For the record, I prefer obscure's approach, *if possible*.  However, that will prevent *all* further events that would have been triggered by the click.  If there are multiple events attached to the click, and you only want to target a specific one to be ignored you may want a scheme something like the following...

```
(function($){
    // creating variables for the event handlers, for cleaner code below
    let tdEvtHandler = function() {
     alert('this is td');
   };

   let bindTd= function() {
     $("#mytable").on("click", "td", tdEvtHandler);
   };

   let btnEvtHandler = function() {
     // The button's evt handler will take precedence when
     // the button is clicked, so you can disable just the
     // td's evt handler at this point, do your work, then
     // re-enable the td's evt handler.  Re-binding needs to
     // be done with a timeout to allow the current event
     // chain to complete before (re)binding takes place.

     $("#mytable").off("click", "td", tdEvtHandler);
     alert('this is button');
     setTimeout(bindTd);
   };

   bindTd();
   $("#mybutton").on("click", btnEvtHandler);
})(jQuery);
```