# How do I prevent parent event handler on a child node?

Tags: javascript

I have a div and it's listend by a event handler:

```js
$('.thediv').click(function() {
  $(this).remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;height:500px">
  <input type="input" style="width:100px;height:20px" />
</div>
```

The div would be removed if it's clicked.

However, I want to put a text input box on the div and if the user clicks the text input, the div should not be removed. Only when the user clicks the area outside the input box, the div get removed.

What can I do?

Comment: read about `event.stopPropagation()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on input click use **.stopPropagation()** this will prevent from call the parent click

```js
$('.thediv').click(function(){$(this).remove()});

$('#input').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<div class="thediv" style="">
  <input type="input" id="input" /><br />
  text here 
  <h1>text here </h1>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `<input onclick="function(e) {e.stopPropagation();});" type="text" style="border: 1px solid;">` inline version does not work. Is there a way to use inline onclick function?

Comment: use only **onclick="event.stopPropagation()"**

Comment: <input onclick="event.stopPropagation()" type="text" style="border: 1px solid;">

Answer (score 4):

Only remove if the target of the event does not match `input`:

```js
$('.thediv').click(function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('input')) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thediv" style="width:500px;height:500px">
  other div content
  <input style="width:100px;height:20px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following demo:

1. `.box` is the parent element that listens for the click event.
2. `.box` is also referred to as `event.currentTarget` because it is registered to the click event.
3. `.box` is also considered `this` within  the callback function.
4. The `event.target` is the origin of the event -- the element that the user clicked.
5. `.box` has an `<input>` child element.
6. The callback function simply states this:

   > *if the clicked element (aka `event.target` -- see #4)
   >
   > is `this` (aka `.box` -- see #3), then...
   >
   > remove `this`*

Note: This will exclude anything within `.box` that is clicked not just an `<input>`.

#### Demo

```js
$('.box').click(function(event) {
  if (this === event.target) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<fieldset class='box' style="width:500px;height:500px">
  <input type="text" style="width:100px;height:20px">
</fieldset>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```