# Why is my form submit button calling a function from another button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I have a button that directs to another website, and a submit input for my form.

When I click the submit button, it calls the function from the other button.

The submit should call validateForm(), but it calls validateRedirect() from the other button as you can see here:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" onclick="validateForm()"></input>

<button type="button" onclick="" >Help</button>
<br /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="validateRedirect()" >Go To Another Website</button> 

<script src="../js/myscript.js">
```

I can't figure out why it is doing it, does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I think this might be a "bubbling" issue. In your validateForm() function try adding "event.preventDefault()"

Comment: Thankyou, it worked.

Comment: Glad it worked. If it is indeed in fact a bubbling issue and you are still having problems you should try event.stopPropagation() (not preventDefault, sorry for the confusion). This is a good explanation between the two
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

Comment: i guess the problem here is that no matter what function you call you will always get redirected because you set that button to `type="submit"`. You think `validateForm()` redirects you but actually you get redirected by the default behaviour of forms