# React-Router Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap components (Card). I want to get redirected to '/abc:id' when clicked on the attachment link. But getting redirected to '/xyz' while wanting it to redirect '/xyz' when clicked on the anywhere on card but Attachment.

```
 <Card
   className={classes.style1}
     onClick={() => history.push({
     pathname: '/xyz'
   })}
 >
   <Card.Body>
      <Link to={'/abc'+id} className="text-info">
         <i className="fas fa-paperclip" />
          <span> Attachment</span>
      </Link>
    </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

Comment: can you show me your routes??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), as currently it is going to `/xyz` after `/abc:id`.

```
<Link
  to={'/abc'+id}
  className="text-info"
  onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
>
```

`stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the event chain. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963688/2873538).

---

Or you can wrap your `Card` in a `Link` and remove `onClick` from Card.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: '/xyz',
  }}
>
  <Card className={classes.style1}>
    <Card.Body>
      <Link to={`/abc${id}`} className="text-info">
        <i className="fas fa-paperclip" />
        <span> Attachment</span>
      </Link>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
</Link>
```

Comment: It works well, but is it the recommended way? Does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: It doesn't have any drawbacks. But it seems better and consistent if you handle both redirection in same manner, using `Link` or `onClick`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, please, and the question if any component renders on that route

```
<Link to={`/abc${id}`} className="text-info">
        <Card.Body>
         <i className="fas fa-paperclip" />
          <span> Attachment</span>
       </Card.Body>
 </Link>
```

Comment: I can't do this because I have other things also in <Card.Body><Card.Body/>, those I haven't mentioned here. And yes on both routes different components are supposed to be rendered. @Anna Vlasenko