# onfocusout runs before navigation trigger

Tags: html, css, razor, blazor, onfocusout

I am experiencing issues triggering a dropdown's navigation when working with onblur or onfocusout in blazor.

The razor page's HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse d-md-inline-flex flex-md-row-reverse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" @onmousedown="e => this.expandSubNavManage = true" @onfocusout="e => this.expandSubNavManage = false">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropdown-button" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle @(expandSubNavManage ? "show" : "")" data-toggle="Manage" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage<SvgImage SvgType="SvgType.CaretDown"></SvgImage></div>
                    </button>
          @if (expandSubNavManage)
          {
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" >
              <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="btn-group-toggle">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary focus" aria-pressed="true">District</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Campus</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                  <NavLink class="nav-link" href="District/Dashboard">
                    <span class="mr-2 svg-style">
                      <SvgImage SvgType="SvgType.Dashboard" SvgClass="svg-style"></SvgImage>
                    </span>
                    Dashboard
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                  <NavLink class="nav-link" href="District/DataManagement">
                    <span class="mr-2">
                      <SvgImage SvgType="SvgType.Data" SvgClass="svg-style"></SvgImage>
                    </span>
                    Data Management
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                  <NavLink class="nav-link" href="District/AutoPilot">
                    <span class="mr-2">
                      <SvgImage SvgType="SvgType.AutoPilot" SvgClass="svg-style"></SvgImage>
                    </span>
                    Auto Pilot
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                  <NavLink class="nav-link" href="District/PerformanceTracker">
                      <span class="mr-2">
                        <span>
                          <SvgImage SvgType="SvgType.PerformanceTracker" SvgClass="svg-style"></SvgImage>
                        </span>
                      </span>
                      Performance Tracker
                  </NavLink>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item px-3">
                  <NavLink class="nav-link" href="District/Tests">
                      <span class="mr-2 ">
                         <SvgImage SvgType="SvgType.Booklet" SvgClass="svg-style"></SvgImage>
                      </span>
                      Tests
                  </NavLink>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      }
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and @code section

```
@code{
  private bool expandSubNavManage;
}
```

Either onblur or onfocusout give me the same issue, it seems that it triggers the "on_" event before registering the navigation trigger. If I delete onfocusout and click a link, the links function. I have tried a solution using a delay, but our SM doesn't want to use this approach.

```
@code{
  private async Task OutFocusManage()
    {
        await Task.delay(50);
        this.expandSubNavManage = false;
    }
}
```

What I'm hoping is to have an eventlistener for my clicked navigation item to send me to a path. Please let me know if there is some way to do this without a forced DELAY.

Comment: Did you resolve this, got the same issue now? Below answer did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add [stopPropagation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#stop-event-propagation) to keep the focus event from "propagating" up the hierarchy and hitting the event handler in your top `li` element too.

In the Microsoft docs example linked above, they show an example stopping the propagation for `@onclick`:

```
<div @onclick="OnSelectParentDiv">
    <div @onclick="OnSelectChildDiv" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
        Child div that stops propagation when selected.
    </div>
</div>
```

In that example, the parent div's `@onclick` handler will NOT be hit.

You need to do the same thing - just with `@onfocusout`.

Your code on each `NavLink` would look something* like:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="District/Dashboard" @onfocusout:stopPropagation="true">
    (your content here)
</NavLink>
```

**Disclaimer: Untested code*

FYI - A similar piece of functionality you should probably be aware of is the "preventDefault" function. While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963688/8026947) is for JS, the answer does a good job demonstrating the differences - the ideas still apply to the Blazor versions of these methods.