# React Typescript event handling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling

I am currently learning React with Typescript and have come across an issue with handling event with the onClick property. I have a react component of a list of stuff from an array and I want to log into the console the item I clicked. It worked when I was referencing the item inline. I was trying to test how it would work if I moved the logic outside to a function and then having onClick reference the function. This is what I have:

[image]

When i do console.log("Clicked, event.currentTarget); it just shows that I clicked the list object, but say for example if I clicked New York I want the console to say "Clicked New York" and not an object with its list of properties. Before I would just have

"<li className="list-group-item" key={item} onClick={() => console.log("Clicked", item)}>;"

and it worked. I tried inspecting the object to see what properties it would have to maybe use the . operator to reference one of them to get the actual item in the array, but I couldn't find anything in the console. Is there a way to actually get the item in the array while using a function to handle the event like I have and if so what would have to be passed as the argument? I was just thinking that this may be necessary for complicated logic while also needing the name of the item in the array that is clicked. I have looked through posts on this topic and can't seem to find one.

Comment: Please can you share the code as text instead of image

Comment: I think you need to prevent event bubbling with ```stopPropagation```, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault

Answer (score 0):

I created a Code Sandbox for you [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-waterfall-1stglb), but here's just one of many possible ways around this:

```
const cities = ["London", "New York", "Paris"];

export default function App() {
  const handleCityClick = (city: string) => console.log(`Clicked ${city}`);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {cities.map((city) => (
          <li key={city} onClick={() => handleCityClick(city)}>
            {city}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-waterfall-1stglb

You'll note that we have to lose the elegance of `onClick={handleClick}` because we actually don't really want to use a mouse event handler any more, we just care about cities. So we have to use a mixture of inline *and* separately-defined handlers to get this; **inline** so that we get the [closed-over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) value of `city` for this `li`, and a **separate function** to avoid putting too much complexity in among all the HTML/JSX.

As you mentioned you might need *both* the `city` *AND* the mouse event, you could of course supply both; e.g.:

```
  const handleCityClick = (city: string, mouseEvent: MouseEvent) => ...

  ...

  <li key={city} onClick={(ev) => handleCityClick(city, ev)}>
```