# prevent redirect on form submit in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, client-side-scripting

I made a form in html that makes login request to this website: https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in
Here is my html code:

```
<form  method="post" class= "login-form" action="https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in">

<input class="login-input--text jcompanycode" id="company_code" name="company_code" type="hidden" value="1234" /> 
<input class="jemail login-input--text" name="email" type="hidden" value="1234" /> 
<input class="jpassword login-input--text" name="password" placeholder="パスワード" type="hidden" value="1234" />
 <input type="submit" value= "submit" id= "submit" /> 
</form>
```

I wrote a javascript code to prevent redirect on submission of form.

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.login-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

I want to prevent redirect on form submission.
However, when i add the javascript, the post request doesn't work. 
Any ideas to send form data to server while remaining on current html page?
Note: please don't tell me to use ajax or jquery to make the login request.
I tried making post request using ajx/jquery a lot of times but it doesn't work. Perhaps due to same origin policy I presume.

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614099/jquery-preventdefault-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614099/jquery-preventdefault-not-working)

Answer (score -2):

HTML form redirect page is its feature.
If you want to avoid, please try to using formdata with ajax.

[MDN FromData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

[MDN Fetch with FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_a_file)